Google service account can't access files in certain shared folders
I'm trying to read files using a Service Account from shared folders using Google API in PHP codes. It works when reading from the shared folders in MyDrive, but not in other shared folders from another department.
The only difference is that the Service Account has "Editor" permission in MyDrive, and "Content Manager" in the shared folders.
My understanding is that it should be able to get all the files that are shared to the Service Account.
Is there any permission or settings that need to be done on the shared folders?
    $credentialsFilePath = 'creds.json';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFilePath);

$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setApplicationName("GoogleDrive");
$client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
$token = $client->getAccessToken();

$accessToken = $token['access_token'];  
 
//get file ID from Google Drive
    $csv_file_name = "File_123.csv";
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$files = array();
    
$parameters = array(
    'q' => "mimeType='text/csv'",
    "orderBy" => "modifiedDate desc"
);

$results = $driveService->files->listFiles($parameters);

foreach($results->getItems() as $file){
    if($file->title == $csv_file_name){
        $drive_file_id = $file->id;
        break;
    }
}

if(empty($drive_file_id)){
    $valErr .= 'File no found!';
}

Thanks in advanced!

is it a google workspace account?  how did you grant the service account access to the data?

In your showing script, you are using $results->getItems() for retrieving the metadata of each file. I think that this is for Drive API v2. Are you required to use Drive API v2 instead of Drive API v3? And, I cannot confirm your goal of your script from your question. Do you want to retrieve the file ID by searching the filename of text/csv from both your drive and shared drives? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Hi Linda, I'm using the share function to give the service account access to the folders

Hi Tanaike, It's an old system that I recently took over. Currently the system allow users to upload the CSV files to Google drive, and keeps the filenames and file ID in database. The system will then retrieve the metadata of a specific file using the file ID stored in the table. Now we're trying to let the users to upload these files directly to their shard folders, and the system will retrieve the files according to the filenames provided, e.g. File_123.csv.  I'm using my own drive for testing and it worked, but not in the users' shared drives

I came across this article about Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account, not sure if this is the root cause. As this folder is under my company's workspace and I don't have administration right o it  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority
